# Transgressive elements in Hopf algebra spectral sequence

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, hopf-algebras

Let $E^r$ be a commutative Hopf algebra homology spectral sequence over $\mathbb{Z}/p$, i.e. such that every sheet is a commutative Hopf algebra.

I am struggling with proving (probably simple) fact - that every transgressive element in such a spectral sequence is primitive.

Comment: How do the differentials interact with the Hopf algebra structure?

Comment: They are morphisms of Hopf algebras, and are derivations w.r.t. multiplication and the tensor product, as far as I understand.

Comment: How can they be both morphisms of Hopf algebras and (co?)derivations?

Comment: Sorry, you are right - a multiplication and comultiplication should be morphisms of spectral sequences. Hopefully it makes sense now